# code for HL7 domain interfaces

Tags: java, hl7

I found some sample code at [the `HL7` web site](http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=10) for defining the interfaces for their `Common Terminology Services`.  It came with some parameters for using `ILDJ` to convert the sample code into Java, for easy importing into my app.

Can anyone show me where to find similar code samples for their `Patient Administration` domain?  And for other `HL7` domains, such as `Care Provision`, `Scheduling`, `Medical Records`, etc.?

At the HL7 web site, [this link](http://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public_temp_54CB52BD-1C23-BA17-0C9686F523AC9903/wg/java/HL7V3Overview.html), I read about the javaSIG version of the `V3 HL7 RIM` Java API.  So I googled one of the package names and found [this link on the HL7 web site](http://www.hl7.org/participate/toolsandresources.cfm?ref=nav).  But as I examine the files for the javaSIG demo zip, I found that the class files were all dated 2005, which seems completely obsolete, even though it claims to support v3 of the RIM.

I then found [this link](http://te.marc-hi.ca/view.aspx?project=6e2de429beae44359a1b23975a90a71b) for the java version of the Everest tool set, which claims to support v3 of the RIM, but it is primarily Canadian and only has 700 downloads.

Tools like [HAPI](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/) seem to only support v2 of the RIM, which is increasingly obsolete.

Can anyone show me how to find the code for the Java api, included packages such as `org.hl7.rim`, in a modern format that is v3 compliant?  In particular, I want to make sure that I get the api for classes like `Encounter`, `Act`, `Patient`, etc. along with the other classes in the domains listed above.  I need access to the class definition code because I need to create an underlying MySQL database to match the class definitions, and also map my current, non-standardized classes to the `HL7 RIM API`.

I would like to avoid having to reinvent the wheel by rolling my own Java versions of their interfaces, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

similar code samples are not published in the same way for things other than CTS.

For java:

- V2: Use the HAPI/MIRTH
- v3: there's the Everest Project
- CDA: There's MDHT
- FHIR: there's java code provided.

I think you're asking about v3 ("care provision domain").

See also http://www.healthintersections.com.au/?p=2029.

Comment: Do you really need to do that? Are you sure? It seems unlikely to me that this is the best way for you to do things. If you really need to do RIM based development, you should seek advice from the HL7 RIM based architecture community (get an HL7 login (hl7.org) and join the "AID" mailing list, and ask for help there)